# Select conditional column but getting subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-studio

I have a database with sales information. There is the CustomerID, FirstName, LastName and State column. In State there are only California and Texas. I need those who live in California to show their FirstName, while those who live in Texas show their LastName.

Perform the following procedure:

```
IF (SELECT State FROM Customer) = 'California'
(SELECT FirstName FROM Customer) 
ELSE 
(SELECT LastName FROM Customer)
```

But there is an error and it appears to me

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Please Help

Comment: As I am not fully qualified as SQL guru, here my 2 cent: What about the where clause in the inner sql statement "(SELECT FirstName FROM Customer)" ? this will always select all customers and thus return more than one row...

Comment: Please don't tag multiple RDBMS - MySQL <> SQL Server. Please correct your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want a conditional, `case`, expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN STATE = 'California' THEN FirstName ELSE LastName END
FROM Customer
```

Points to note:

- You want to use set-based logic as much as possible in SQL. And avoid procedural logic (IF/THEN/END).
- You are always going to get the error you got if you try and compare a single value to the results of a query which returns more than one value. This is where you need a `WHERE` clause and/or a `TOP 1` followed by an `ORDER BY`.
- In fact you almost always want to have both a `WHERE` clause to filter the results, and and `ORDER BY` to order them. You might want to revisit your SQL tutorials on this one.